# C# Passing StringBuilder in a ListboxItems Content

Tags: c#, listbox, type-conversion, stringbuilder

I have a `listbox` in which i pass in every row 5 items. My XML file looks like this :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="DatabaseBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Book}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto" Height="22">
             <Image x:Name="ToggleFavoriteImage" Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding City}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Country}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Where `Book` is a `private static List<BookItems> Book{ get; set; }` and `BookItems` is

```
    public struct BookItems
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Author{ get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
    }
```

All my data that i want to pass in `ListBox` are stored in another `List` :`private static List<Tuple<StringBuilder , StringBuilder , StringBuilder , StringBuilder , StringBuilder >> BookList = new List<Tuple<StringBuilder , StringBuilder , StringBuilder , StringBuilder , StringBuilder >>();`

So if i try to fill my `ListBox` that way :

```
 foreach(var ListItem in BookList)
 {
    Book= new List<BookItems>() 
    {
      new BookItems() 
      {
         Tag = ListItem.Item1.ToString(),ImageSource = FavoriteSource, Name= ListItem.Item1.ToString(), Author= ListItem.Item3.ToString(), City = ListItem.Item4.ToString(),Country = ListItem.Item5.ToString()
       }
     };
     DatabaseBox.Items.Add(Book);
 }
```

then i get everywhere `null` except the image. If i change my `BookList` to `strings` and my Book also, then everything goes smooth without any problems. I check every time the convertions from `StringBuilder` to `string` with a Console outpout and my `strings` are null, where my StringBuilder is ok. Am i doing something so wrong?

Comment: why do u use 'stringBuilder' for every part of the Tuple and how do you fetch your data

Comment: Its my a project from my university and asks to use StringBuilder. As for the fetching, i read from an XML File and pass them with BookList.Add(Tuple.Create(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)); where x1,x2... are temp StringBuilders.

Comment: have you try debugging it? saw that you get values off the xml? can you tell me where the problem starts?

Comment: The problem starts in the conversion from StringBuilder - ToString(). I fill my stringbuilder list just fine, the problem is with the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You should create instances for StringBuilder items in tuple like new StringBuilder()

Comment: Nope, in this one complirer error. But why should i do new StringBuilder()?? I fill my StringBuilder List just fine.

Answer (score 0):

as you said, the stringBuilder is just fine so my solution to you is first of all do not create a list for every item. i don't know why are you doing it but there shouldn't be a list for every item you add to DatabaseBox.

second, take your code

```
Book= new List<BookItems>() 
{
  new BookItems() 
  {
     Tag = ListItem.Item1.ToString(),ImageSource = FavoriteSource, Name= ListItem.Item1.ToString(), Author= ListItem.Item3.ToString(), City = ListItem.Item4.ToString(),Country = ListItem.Item5.ToString()
   }
 };
```

and rewrite it. also rewrite the properties in `BookItems` and make it a class.
after you do all of that the debug process will be easy. if the `stringBuilders` contains the data you will see exactly what happens to it.